# Find the whole series below

Tags: calculus

I've been having some problems with these two series.

\begin{align}&\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{n}{3^n}\\&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+2}\right)\end{align}

The first seems similar to a geometric series but I don't know what to do with that extra n n.

The second I really just don't know what to do either.

I'd really appreciate any help you can give me, thanks!

Comment: For $|p|<1$ one has $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot p^n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot p^n = \frac{p}{(p-1)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

The second goes
$$\left(\frac11+\frac12\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac13\right)
+\left(\frac13+\frac14\right)-\left(\frac14+\frac15\right)+\cdots.$$
I reckon that telescopes.

The first is a special case of $\sum nx^n$ (for $x=-1/3$)
which looks a bit like what you get when you differentiate $\sum x^n$.